# How do I trim this

Tags: php

```
http://www.trafficestimate.com/,http://getclicky.com/,http://technotarget.com/find-out-who-is-visiting-your-site-website-traffic-tools/,http://pmetrics.performancing.com/
```

The above are sample websites for trimming. I want to extract only the domain names from above, for example: `trafficestimate.com,getclicky.com,technotarget.com,performancing.com`

How can I do this with PHP? I am talking about a lot more web addresses like this, not only the above one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure, let's see how this can be done. First, we need to break these URLs into individual components. We can do this by using the [explode](https://www.php.net/explode) command:

```
$urls = "http://www.trafficestimate.com/,http://getclicky.com/,http://technotarget.com/find-out-who-is-visiting-your-site-website-traffic-tools/,http://pmetrics.performancing.com/";

$url_array = explode(",", $urls);
```

What this does is take the URLs you have, and put them into an array by separating them on the comma. Let's see what a sample result looks like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://www.trafficestimate.com/
    [1] => http://getclicky.com/
    [2] => http://technotarget.com/find-out-who-is-visiting-your-site-website-traffic-tools/
    [3] => http://pmetrics.performancing.com/
)
```

Nifty eh? Now then, the next step is to loop through all the results, which can be done with a simple [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop. But before we do, we need someplace to store the result domains. We declare an empty array:

```
$domains = array();
```

Now we can loop over the results:

```
$domains = array();
foreach($url_array as $url) {
  // actions here
}
```

So, what do we need to do for each result? We need the domain name. PHP actually has a nice function to parse urls called [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php). The alternative to this is to use more complicated measures, so this works out nicely! Here is our updated code:

```
$domains = array();
foreach($url_array as $url) {
  $parsed_url = parse_url($url);
}
```

Now then, let's see what `parse_url` gives us:

```
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => pmetrics.performancing.com
    [path] => /
)
```

Notice that host? It's the domain name we're trying to get a hold of. So we'll add that to our array of domains:

```
$domains = array();
foreach($url_array as $url) {
  $parsed_url = parse_url($url);
  $domains[] = $parsed_url['host'];
}
```

Now let's see what the result is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => www.trafficestimate.com
    [1] => getclicky.com
    [2] => technotarget.com
    [3] => pmetrics.performancing.com
)
```

That's it! `$domain` now holds all the domain names. If we want to print them separated by commas like above, we can use the [implode](https://www.php.net/implode) command to do so:

```
echo implode(',', $domains);
```

Which gives us:

```
www.trafficestimate.com,getclicky.com,technotarget.com,pmetrics.performancing.com
```

And that's all there is too it! Here is the full code listing for your reference:

```
$urls = "http://www.trafficestimate.com/,http://getclicky.com/,http://technotarget.com/find-out-who-is-visiting-your-site-website-traffic-tools/,http://pmetrics.performancing.com/";

$url_array = explode(",", $urls);

$domains = array();
foreach($url_array as $url) {
  $parsed_url = parse_url($url);
  $domains[] = $parsed_url['host'];
}

echo implode(',', $domains);
```

Answer (score 2):

like so:

```
$input = explode(',', $input);
```

and then for each value:

```
$input[$k] = preg_replace('/^https?://(?:www\.)?/i', '', $input[$k]);
```

Answer (score 2):

[Parse URL](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
// get host name from URL
preg_match("/^(http:\/\/)?([^\/]+)/i",
    "http://www.example.com/index.html", $matches);
$host = $matches[2];

// get last two segments of host name
preg_match("/[^\.\/]+\.[^\.\/]+$/", $host, $matches);
echo "domain name is: {$matches[0]}\n";

/* Output is example.com */

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternately you can use this function to get the domain only.

```
    function GetDomain($url)
{
$nowww = ereg_replace('www\.','',$url);
$domain = parse_url($nowww);
if(!empty($domain["host"]))
    {
     return $domain["host"];
     } else
     {
     return $domain["path"];
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$urls = 'http://www.trafficestimate.com/,http://getclicky.com/,http://technotarget.com/find-out-who-is-visiting-your-site-website-traffic-tools/,http://pmetrics.performancing.com/';
$hosts = array_map(function ($url) { return parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST); }, explode(',', $urls));

var_dump($hosts);
```

Note that this returns `pmetrics.performancing.com` for example, which is the correct way to do it though. There's no rule that says only the TLD and first subdomain are *"the domain"*, the complete hostname is the domain.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$input = explode(',', $input);
$urls = array();
foreach($input as $item){
   $url = parse_url($item);
   $urls[] = $item[host];
}
?>
```